# Find a non-Noetherian ring that has an ideal which does not contain any power of its own radical

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Find a non-Noetherian ring and show that there exists some ideal $I$ where $\nexists n \in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $[rad(I)]^n\subset I$

I have found some non Noetherian rings such as the ring of algebraic integers or the ring of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ but I cant find any ideal that does not contain any power of its radical.

Any discussion on that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be field, Let $R$ be the ring of polynomials in infinitely many variables
$R:=K[x_{1},x_{2},\cdots] $, $R$ isn't Noetherian, this can be seen by considering the ascending chain of ideals $I_{k} :=<x_{1},\cdots, x_{k}>$.
Consider the ideal $I=<x_{1}^{2},x_{2}^{3},\cdots, x_{n} ^{n+1},\cdots >$, then $Rad(I) =<x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{n} ,\cdots >$, Now it is clear that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, Rad(I) ^{n} \nsubseteq I$

Comment: I am trying to understand why this is clear. What is the form of the elements in $Rad(I)^n$ or what are the generators of $Rad(I)^n$?. However thank you very much for your answer, it is really helpful.

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas u are welcome. In general if $I$ is an ideal, then elements of $I^{n}$ has the form $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{1}^{i}a_{2}^{i} \cdots a_{n}^{i}$,where all $a_{j}^{i}\in I$,that is the power of an ideal consists of finite sums of prodcts of elements of the ideal.Now $Rad(I)^{n}=<x_{1}^{n},x_{1}^{n-1}x_{2},x_{1}^{n-1}x_{3},x_{1}^{n-1}x_{4},\cdots ;x_{1}x_{2}..x_{n};.......>$;so we are sure that $x_{n}^{n} \in Rad(I)^{n} \setminus I$

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!